# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql

While I am trying to insert a row to my table, I'm getting the following errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''filename') 
VALUES ('san', 'ss', 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 'sment', 'notes','sant' at line 1
```

please help me out.

```
mysql> desc risks;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| status          | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| subject         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| reference_id    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| location        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| category        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| team            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| technology      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| owner           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| manager         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| assessment      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| notes           | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| submission_date | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| last_update     | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| review_date     | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| mitigation_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| mgmt_review     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| project_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| close_id        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| submitted_by    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| filename        | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)

**mysql> INSERT INTO risks (`status`, `subject`, `reference_id`, `location`, `category`,
`team`, `technology`, `owner`, `manager`, `assessment`, `notes`,'filename')     VALUES 
('san', 'ss', 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 'sment', 'notes','santu');**

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''filename') 
VALUES ('san', 'ss', 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 'sment', 'notes','sant' at line 1
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are two different types of quotation marks in MySQL. You need to use ` for column names and ' for strings. Since you have used ' for the filename column the query parser got confused. Either remove the quotation marks around all column names, or change 'filename' to `filename`. Then it should work.

Answer (score 5):

This error comes when you have a column that is one of the MySQL keywords. Try to run your queries with all of your column names in back ticks. For example:

```sql
insert into test (`sno`, `order`, `category`, `samp`, `pamp`, `method`) values(1, 1, 'top', 30, 25, 'Total');
```

Column name `order` is a keyword in MySQL, so I had to put that in `` quotes.

Comment: Generally while naming columns in our table we do not keep keywords in mind, so better put all the columns in **``** quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Don't quote the column filename

```
mysql> INSERT INTO risks (status, subject, reference_id, location, category, team,    technology, owner, manager, assessment, notes,filename) 
VALUES ('san', 'ss', 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 'sment', 'notes','santu');
```

Answer (score 3):

This Error comes due to same table exist in 2 database like you have a database for project1 and in which you have table emp and again you have another database like project2 and in which you have table emp then when you try to insert something inside the database with-out your database name then you will get an error like about

Solution for that when you use mysql query then also mention database name along with table name.

OR

**Don't Use Reserved key words like KEY as column name**

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\xampp>mysql -u root -p mydatabase < C:\DB_Backups\stage-new.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear 'stage-new.sql

----lot of space----

' at line 1
```

The reason was when I dumped the DB I used following command :

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <username> -p <database> > dumpfile.sql
dumpfile.sql
```

By mistaken dumpfile.sql added twice in the syntax.

**Solution :** I removed the *dumpfile.sql* text added to first line of the exported dumpfile.

Answer (score 1):

Save code below as command.sql

```sql
USE restaurant
TRUNCATE `orders`;
TRUNCATE `order_items`;
```

Then run

```sh
mysql -u root <comands.sql> output.tab
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for windows:

1. Open command prompt in Administrator Mode.
2. Goto path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
3. Run below command:
   mysqldump -h 127.0.01 -u root -proot db table1 table2 > result.sql

Answer (score 0):

**I encountered this same error:**
*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', completed)' at line 1*

**This was the input I had entered on terminal:**
mysql> create table todos (description, completed);

**Solution:** *For each column type you must specify the type of content they will contain. This could either be text, integer, variable, boolean there are many different types of data.*

mysql> create table todos (description text, completed boolean);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

It now passed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the values below were first written ( multiple lines) as follows in the sql dump file:

```
-- SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '33ce20a2-ad12-11ec-bdac-3238639baa41:1-9133,
7dd21400-4a0f-11ec-a3f9-aa2aaded1a97:1-5031,
a8ffc1f8-6888-11eb-9a01-3671a0dcaa62:1-9355,
dce51f13-7f37-11ea-9882-627116a92c36:1-6177,
f1115a53-0a94-11ed-8ccd-923c66acbd99:1-1584';
```

Fixed after making them all in one line:

```
*-- SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '33ce20a2-ad12-11ec-bdac-3238639baa41:1-9133,7dd21400-4a0f-11ec-a3f9-aa2aaded1a97:1-5031,a8ffc1f8-6888-11eb-9a01-3671a0dcaa62:1-9355,dce51f13-7f37-11ea-9882-627116a92c36:1-6177,f1115a53-0a94-11ed-8ccd-923c66acbd99:1-1584';*
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem can be solved in 2 methods

1.Change filename to something else as SQL considers some words as keywords that will solve the issue
2.Simply Change the Quote Style to ''(this), but I would suggest the first option is better for the long run.

I hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE information (
 id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 age INT(10) NOT NULL,
 salary INT(100) NOT NULL,
 address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );
```

Answer (score -1):

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<

Very simple question that you can solved it easily: change `<` to `(` and `>;` to `);`

Just use:

```
( 
               
          
       
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE information (
-> id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
-> age INT(10) NOT NULL,
-> salary INT(100) NOT NULL,
-> address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY(id)
-> );
```

Comment: Maybe the answer will become even better if you just design it. I mean there is a `enter code` section which you may remove. There is a `);`.

Comment: This is the better solution for this problem because this is updated result ! if you write >; it  than you will face a problem But if you write this ); it will success!

Answer (score -2):

Execute dump query in terminal then it will work

```
mysql -u root -p  <Database_Name> > <path of the input file>
```

Comment: fixed it for me . Actual helpful message