# SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax while running query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

While I am trying to select a table on a MySQL data base, I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table_1 as (

    SELECT
        user_id,
        age
    FROM example_table

)

S' at line 3

Error position: line: 2
```

Below I included the query:

```
WITH

table_1 as (

    SELECT
        user_id,
        age
    FROM example_table

)

SELECT * FROM table_1;
```

I checked different contributions on StackOverflow and other sites (like [ERROR 1064 (42000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009582/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that) and [Fix ERROR 1064 (42000) while creating a database in MySQL?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fix-error-1064-42000-while-creating-a-database-in-mysql#:%7E:text=The%20ERROR%201064%20(42000)%20mainly,in%20ERROR%201064%20(42000).)
). I am aware there is some syntax error but I am not able to find a solution.

Help is really appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: You can safely assume that `table` is a reserved keyword in probably every RDBMS.

Comment: @David, I find no exceptions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Comment: @David there is also an error with another naming than table

Comment: @Albin: Is it the exact same error, in the exact same place?  "There is also an error" isn't very specific.  Perhaps you could update the question?

Comment: @David I'm sorry - yes, it is the same error. I also edited the question by replacing table with table_1

Comment: Probably you are using an older `MySQL` version which does not support `WITH` clause. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac12e0cb53ebf5bb90977801ecebf3dc

Comment: @Ergest Basha thanks a lot! That is actually the cause of the error